# R- Assigning value on conditions of multiple other variables & handling missing data

Tags: r, missing-data

I am a MD researching in epidemiology and am new to both R and the forum but will try to make a clear and concise post.

I am working with a dataframe called COHORT1 and I am having trouble creating a new numeric variable on the conditions of 2 other factors in the same dataframe.

Problem no 1.

I want to create a new numeric variable HF that is assigned the value 1 whenever the factor HJ8F has one of the following values: 
"Cor incomp", "Cor. inkomp", "hjärtsvikt", "Hjärtsvikt", "Hjärtsvikt UNS", "Hjärtinsufficiens", 
OR when the factor HJ8F2 has one of the follwoing values: "I50", "I50.9". If they do not contain any of the above values HF should be assigned the value 0, if HJ8F AND HJ8F" are empty/missing HF should be missing too.

If I try:

```
COHORT1$HF <-NA
COHORT1$HF <- ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Cor incomp", 1, ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Cor. inkomp", 1, 
ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="hjärtsvikt", 1, ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Hjärtsvikt", 1,
ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Hjärtsvikt UNS", 1, ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Hjärtinsufficiens", 1,
ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F2=="I50", 1, ifelse(COHORT1$HJ8F2=="I50.9", 1,0))))))))

summary(COHORT1$HF)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0       0       0       0       0       0 
> sum(is.na(COHORT1$HF))
[1] 0
```

I can't print you all the data because there are about 15 000 rows but I noticed that there are some blank spaces in the HJ8F and HJ8F2 variable. This would not explain that no HF are assigned the value 1.

If I used trim to remove blank spaces the factors Hj8F and Hj8F2 convert to characters

```
library(gdata) #for trim function

#remove blank spaces from variable
COHORT1$HJ8F_trimmed <- trim(COHORT1$HJ8F)
```

Solution and Problem no 2.

If I then run the ifelse command above but use the trimmed versions of HJ8F and HJ8F2 it works fine (HF==1 when it should be) except for that the trimmed versions are non-missing when empty which leads to HF being assigned the value 0 instead of missing in those cases.

Thinking it was a problem of factors vs Characters i also tried:

```
COHORT1$HF <- ifelse(as.character(COHORT1$HJ8F=="Cor incomp"), 1, ifelse...
```

but that also leads to all HF values being 0

Any solutions to Problems 1 and/or 2 greatly appreciated. I also tried to assign HF the value NA when HJ8F and HJ8F2 were NA but could not get it to work:

```
> COHORT1$HF <- if(COHORT1$HJ8F=="" || COHORT1$HJ8F2=="") COHORT1$HF=NA
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Adding new column 'HF' then assigning NULL (deleting it).
> summary(COHORT1$HF)
Length  Class   Mode 
 0   NULL   NULL 
>
```

Let me know if you need more info or clarification.

Thank you

Some output as requested by nicola:
(dput did not output the requested info but i think i got what you need below:)

```
> summary(COHORT1$HJ8F)

14343
 Hjärtsvikt

63
Cor incomp

22
Förmaksflimmer

17 
 Hjärtsvikt UNS

10
Corincomp

6
 Hjärtinsufficiens

6 
Cor. incomp
```

And 20 first rows for for Hj8F2(column 40)

```
> COHORT1[1:20,40]
 [1]                                                                                                                
 [8]                                                                                                                
[15]                 I50.9                                                                          
76 Levels:                 138.P           1489B           I00.9               I01.1           ... Z95.0          
>
```

I would like HF to be assigned the value 1 for all HJ8F identical to or containing the following: Hjärtsvikt, Cor incomp, Hjärtsvikt UNS, Corincomp, Hjärtinsufficiens and Cor. incomp OR HJ8F2 equal to I50.9 or I50.

while being assigned 0 for all other values of HJ8F/HJ8F2, if HJ8F/HJ8F2 are missing or empty HF should be missing to.

Comment: Share some data. Post the output of `dput(COHORT[1:20,c("HJ8F","HJ8F2")])` (i.e. the first 20 lines of your input dataset with just the needed columns) and states what should be your desired output for these first 20 cases.

Comment: I don't know if this solves your problem - but it might make it easier to see what is going on if you use `%in%` instead of lots of `==`'s

Comment: Thanks for the input, did not know about %in% - seems useful too. Solved it using grepl that can match patterns more flexibly. Turned out that most data was unusable though as the "n" in the first line in the summary output actually represented the number of elements containing only "empty spaces".

grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
      fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)